# How can I remove a newline character from the line above in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a string which has been split anytime that a single line goes over 69 characters. In order to process it, I would like to restore it to how it was pre-split. A split line always starts with a forward slash character on the second and subsequent lines, which needs to be kept. Is there a nice Ruby way to do this?

```
# Split version
GTSS/230028GG/JUL15/LL:123456X3-0051234G4/DES/000G/57NM/57NM/095T
/002GTS////gts

# Required output
GTSS/230028GG/JUL15/LL:123456X3-0051234G4/DES/000G/57NM/57NM/095T/002GTS////gts
```

I'm happy matching a line that starts with the forward slash. What I don't know is how to remove the newline character from end of the previous line.

```
example.lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
  if line.match(/^\/.+$/)
    # what goes here?
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show an example with 3 lines of input (6 lines total). You need to have your regex match on each pair of lines and output without the extra carriage return.

Comment: You might have come up with the answer yourself had you phrased the question differently and, arguably, more precisely: "How can I substitute a forward slash for every newline character followed by a forward slash?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `gsub`:

```
string = "GTSS/230028GG/JUL15/LL:123456X3-0051234G4/DES/000G/57NM/57NM/095T\n/002GTS////gts"
string.gsub("\n/", '/')
#=> "GTSS/230028GG/JUL15/LL:123456X3-0051234G4/DES/000G/57NM/57NM/095T/002GTS////gts"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `lstrip`it will remove all whitespace(space, newline...) from left:

```
example.lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
  if line.match(/^\/.+$/)
    line.lstrip
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

.`strip` will remove all whitespace(space, newline...) the whole string

Answer (score 0):

Another way (but I like @spickermann's answer better):

```
str = "GTSS/230028GG/JUL15/LL:123456X3-0051234G4/DES/000G/57NM/57NM/095T
/002GTS////gts"

str.split("\n/").join("/")
  #=> "GTSS/230028GG/JUL15/LL:123456X3-0051234G4/DES/000G/57NM/57NM/095T/002GTS////gts"
```